# How do I invert tablet orientation?

Tags: 20.04, tablet, input-devices

I have a Zinnia Momentum MT-100 tablet that I'm trying to use on 20.04 and it works on plug and everything, the only issue is that the orientation is wrong. It's detecting horizontal inputs as vertical and vice versa. I've tried to search a solution but all of the tutorials and forum replies refer specifically to Wacom tablets. would the Wacom settings work on non-Wacom tablets? if not, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As muriki said, you need to insert the code line

```
 Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "<your tablet name>"
        MatchUSBID "<lsusb code>"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "wacom"
  Option "Rotate" "ccw"
EndSection
```

You'll need to insert this by using `sudo vi 70-wacom.conf` (also works with other editors)
The tablet name must be the one that you can get by `lsusb` so this probably was the thing that made it doesn't work for you.
(in my case, the name that was gotten by lsusb was 'Gotop Information Inc. [T605] Driver Inside Tablet', for example)
Hope it works for you, my friend.

Comment: oh my god that was it! it worked!! thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Today arrived my zinnia momentum MT-100 and I had exactly the same problem, but in arch linux. I solved following the Graphics tablet arch wiki:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Graphics_tablet#Tablet_recognized_but_xsetwacom_and_similar_tools_do_not_display_it

Basically, you have to install the wacom xsetwacom command line tool. Then check using `xsetwacom list devices` to see if the tool recognizes the tablet.

If it don't recognize, check if you have a InputClass in the file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-wacom.conf`.
In my case I had to add the following to the conf file:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Zinnia tablet"
        MatchUSBID "2345:6789"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "wacom"
  Option "Rotate" "ccw"
EndSection
```

The MatchUSBID is the ID in `lsusb` that refers to your tablet.

Finally, if the xsetwacom recognized your tablet, then you just need to rotate using the command `xsetwacom --set <ID> Rotate ccw`. Where ID is the stylus ID in `xsetwacom list devices`.

xsetwacom commands: https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsetwacom

If something still don't work, I strongly recommend to read the Graphics tablet wiki.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i followed through your instructions but for some reason i can't get `xsetwacom` to recognize my tablet...